# How to hide a div when checkbox is selected - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I have this structure and I want to hide the div class "categorydesc" when I check something from the checklist...
How can I do that?

```
<ul id="ul_layered_id_feature_10" class="col-lg-12">
<li id="layered_id_feature_10" class="checkbox" >
<input class="checkbox" name="layered_id_feature_10" id="layered_id_feature_10" type="checkbox">
<label for="layered_id_feature_10">test</label>
</li>
<li id="layered_id_feature_9" class="checkbox" >
<input class="checkbox" name="layered_id_feature_9" id="layered_id_feature_9" type="checkbox">
<label for="layered_id_feature_9">test</label>
</li>
</ul>

<div class="categorydesc">
<p>test</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Why so many irrelevant tags? Do add some code.

Comment: You dont have any actual checkboxes in your checklist

Comment: there are probably hundreds of questions and answers around this sort of thing on SO; do some research first please before you post a question

Comment: Where are checkbox?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this more simply, using `toggle` method.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#checkbox').change(function(){
       $('#container').toggle();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"> Display
<hr/>
<div id="container" style="display:none;">
test
</div>
```

Comment: I used style="display:block; because I want to hide it when I check something...it works for that but when I uncheck the box it not changing the value of the style="display:none; in to display:block

Answer (score 0):

hope this will work

```
$('.checkbox').change(function(){
    if(this.checked)
        $('somediv').fadeIn('slow');
    else
        $('somediv').fadeOut('slow');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#checker').change(function(){
      if($(this).is(':checked'))
      {
       $('#data').show();
      }
      else
      {
       $('#data').hide();
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="checker"> Display
<hr/>
<div id="data" style="display:none;">
em Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
</div>
```

What we are doing here is:

we listen for a change event of our checkbox with id = checker.

As soon as a change is detected, we check if the checkbox has been checked or unchecked.

If it is checked then we show the div with id data otherwise hide it.

You can use the above snippet in your case too, by modifying it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I have set some code for you. It is working. I hope this will be helpful for you.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('input.myCheckbox').click(function(){
   if($(this).prop('checked')) {
   alert(1);
    $('.categorydesc').hide();
   }
   else{
    $('.categorydesc').show();
   }
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ul_layered_id_feature_10" class="col-lg-12">

  <li id="layered_id_feature_10" class="checkbox">
    Test<input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox" />
  </li>
  <li id="layered_id_feature_9" class="checkbox">
    Test<input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox" />
  </li>

</ul>

<div class="categorydesc">
 <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Works. But there is a problem...when I uncheck the element the .show property is not working....

Comment: <div id="categorydesc" class="row category hidden-xs hidden-sm" style="display: none;">  style="display: none; is set in motion when I check something but the display property is not changing to display:block when I uncheck the element...

Comment: You can try something like this when uncheck: $('.categorydesc').css("display","block"); instead of "$('.categorydesc').show();" if show is not working for you.